# Is there any way to get DocuSign Nory Signing URL

Tags: docusignapi

I would like to embed Docusign Notay Session in one of my web application.

For the normal case I am using the following code to get the URL

```
RecipientViewRequest viewRequest = MakeRecipientViewRequest(notaryEmail, notaryName, _redirectURL);
                ViewUrl viewURL = envelopesApi.CreateRecipientView(accountId, retval.EnvelopeID, viewRequest);
```

Currently I am trying to create envelop using "CreateEnvelope"  method it is throwing the following exception

Code:-

```
var notaryHost = new NotaryHost
                    {
                        Name = notaryName,
                        Email = notaryEmail,
                        DeliveryMethod = "email",
                        RecipientId = notaryId,
                        ClientUserId = "1000"
                    };
```

Error:-

{"errorCode":"NOTARY_CAPTIVE_RECIPIENT_NOT_SUPPORTED","message":"A notary recipient cannot be a captive recipient. This operation is not supported."}

Is there any way to get the URL for DocuSign Notary session?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately embedded Notary signing is not yet supported.

Please ask your DocuSign technical, sales, or business development contact to add your company information to internal ticket NTRY-634.